# What is the name of this extinct type symbol?

Tags: typography, typesetting, symbols, unicode

This text is from a facsimile of a 1949 manuscript of that quotes Psalm 106 (107), and the quoted passage is from verse 26.

[image: [text](]

The word is that uses the symbol is `"usque"` Latin for "always" but `"-que"` means "and".

What is the name of the last symbol on the first line and the highlighted symbol?
Is there a Unicode for the symbol?

Comment: Searching for "que ligature" I find two questions on other stacks that answer your question. [This on literature](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/12023/what-are-these-letters-in-unicode) and [this on tex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68007/typesetting-an-old-latin-ligature-with-pdftex).

Comment: I found one in Latin also.  Perhaps it was a precursor to the semicolon.

Comment: _Usque_ means ‘always’, not ‘and’ (although the suffix _-que_ does mean ‘and’). It’s not related to the semicolon, which was invented from scratch by Aldus Manutius in Italy in 1496. Its meaning and usage has varied considerably, but a ligature for _et_ being used with the letter q to write the sequence _que_ is not related to it.

Answer (score 4):

**vſqꝫ**

It is a ligature between *q* and *ꝫ* `U+A76B LATIN SMALL LETTER ET`. The ligature itself in encoded in the private use area of the Medieval Unicode Font Initative [MUFI](https://mufi.info) as `U+E8BF LATIN SMALL LETTER Q LIGATED WITH FINAL ET`.

It was encoded in the [Latin Extended-D block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_Extended-D), with many other medieval abbreviation characters from the MUFI following [this proposal](https://www.unicode.org/L2/L2006/06101-n3060.pdf).